# Mongoose - save document Object.assign

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

I have a mongoose document, and i want to update many fields on it with another object. something like

```
Model.findById(_id, function (err, doc){
    var updateData = {...data}

    // i do not want to do 
    doc.foo = data.foo;
    doc.bar = data.bar;

    // i need something like
    doc.save(updateData)
    // or
    doc.update(updateData)
    // or
    doc = {...doc, ...updateData}
    doc.save();

});
```

the updateData is a object with all the data i need to update in the doc.

didn't found any doc related, the closest was a find one and update...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your `data` object has all of the keys you want to update on the document, why don't you try using `Object.assign` as you mention in the title of your question:

```
Object.assign(doc, data);
doc.save(callback); // save is async
```

Or you can use Mongo's `.findByIAndUpdate()` like so:

```
Model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $set: data }, callback)
```

Either way, you can avoid manually setting each property you want to update.

Comment: but i'm afraid the `Object.assign` may override the setters/getters or any important properties of the mongoose object. This will happens?

Comment: I think you should be okay per the `Object.assign` [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). `Object.assign` uses `get` on the source and `set` on the target (in this case, your document), therefore it **assigns** properties verses just copying them, so it should adhere to any predefined getters/setters

Comment: Great! i was thinking in use spread operator, something like `{..doc, ...data}` but this will create another object and won't keep the mongoose doc.

Comment: But I have one last question to confirm, using Object.assign(doc, data), nested objects will be replaced or they will obey the getters/setters from mongoose document?

Comment: @Maxwells.c Were you able to confirm that this was ok?

Comment: @AdamD yes i think. i made this question long ago and don't remember but i checked it as the correct answer so it works

Answer (score 0):

try this

// update

```
router.put("/updatestudent/:id", function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    var obj = req.body;
    student.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { name: obj.name, emailid: obj.emailid },
        function(err) {
            if (err) {
                return res.send('error updated student');
            }
            res.send("updated");
        });
});
```

Comment: sorry, but i need to work with the current object, i'm trying to not search the item again